# Query and Visualize GeoJSON data

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I am trying to visualize specific GeoJSON data.

I am successfully loading the full GeoJSON file (Multipolygon) using Leaflet JS. Is there any query to find specific polygon from that GeoJSON file?

For an example I am using USA state GeoJSON data. I am using a dropdown list to call specific states such as California - CA. How can I call that specific GeoJSON data of where state = California?

Comment: What do you mean by 'call specific states'? You need to give us more information about what exactly you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html

Filter
The filter option can be used to control the visibility of GeoJSON features. To accomplish this we pass a function as the filter option. This function gets called for each feature in your GeoJSON layer, and gets passed the feature and the layer. You can then utilise the values in the feature's properties to control the visibility by returning true or false.

In the example below "Busch Field" will not be shown on the map.

```
var someFeatures = [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "name": "Coors Field",
        "show_on_map": true
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-104.99404, 39.75621]
    }
}, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "name": "Busch Field",
        "show_on_map": false
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-104.98404, 39.74621]
    }
}];

L.geoJson(someFeatures, {
    filter: function(feature, layer) {
        return feature.properties.show_on_map;
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

Or you can parse your geojson manually:

```
var json = {
    "people": {
        "person": [{
            "name": "Peter",
            "age": 43,
            "sex": "male"},
        {
            "name": "Zara",
            "age": 65,
            "sex": "female"}]
    }
};
$.each(json.people.person, function(i, v) {
    if (v.name == "Peter") {
        alert(v.age);
        return;
    }
});
```